# Customized Logging interceptor with bean value in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, customization, interceptor, actioncontext

I am writing a customized interceptor for audit logs purpose.
I want to get session attributes and request attributes in interceptor.

For example: I'll set `Username` into session and that I am getting too.

But the challenge is: I am defining one bean as audit bean where I am setting some values to bean

```java
if (this.userName.equals("admin")) {
    user.setUserName(this.userName);
    sessionAttributes.put("USER", user);
    auditBean.setPerm("login success");
    requestAttributes.put("auditBean", auditBean);
    return "success";
} else {
    auditBean.setPerm("Login Failed initiaqlized");
    requestAttributes.put("auditBean", auditBean);
    addActionError(getText("error.login"));
    
    return "error";
}
```

this request attribute is `ServletRequestAware` obj.
But this audit bean I am not able to retrieve into the interceptor, please help regarding this.

```java
Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
```

achieving session like this.

```java
Map<String, Object> requestAttributes = invocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters();
```

with above I am not able to retrieve request params.
It's showing JSP request params, but not that I have set in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that an invocation context in your interceptor is your action context, then get it directly from the context map.

```
Map<String, Object> requestAttributes = (Map<String, Object>) invocation.getInvocationContext().get("request");
```

or use alternate syntax

```
Map requestAttributes = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().get("request");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
This is the alternate way to retrieve request object

```
 HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

But If you want to achieve the requestattribute which set into the action you need retrieve that after invocation.
e.g.

```
 String result =  invocation.invoke();
```

after this

```
AuditBean auditBean2=(AuditBean) request.getAttribute("auditLogs");
```

then request object will not be null and you will get the value also.